# What is the translation and meaning of the Mordekhai HaArokh on Shulchan Aruch O"C 155?

Tags: halacha, commentaries, eating, shulchan-aruch

On SAOC 155:2 – what is the meaning and translation of the Mordekhai haArokh here, particularly the bolded part? Would the following be correct?

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91

Pat Shacharit – My teacher and father in law (the Bach) z"l quotes the Mordekhai haArokh, "Now you've asked me to explain what should be the quantity of Pat Shacharit and what time of day to eat it. Know that it's not our custom at all and our rabbis don't have a habit of it, on account that we've heard that Pat Shacharit **can only be eaten with produce far from the city, and the time is neither [early as] when the rooster crows nor [late as] when those that tug the boats are heard;** whereas those that practice it would need to eat it at a fixed time every day. Therefore the chakhamim refrain from it, because they won't be able to fulfill it." [Now the Taz in footnote 1 brings this, except he wrote that] "But whoever disregards this and performs it in simplicity has nothing to lose." [So too wrote the M"A in footnote 3 about this Morkekhai that they are not serious halakhic words and that the Gemara doesn't seem that way; see there. So too the Responsa of Chakham Tzvi #15 wrote, see there, 2:4. So did the MT"Y #2 write, as the words of the Shas imply that regarding plain bread, everything states that it eliminates hunger, and not like the opinion of the Mordekhai haArokh, and he wrote "the Tur's opinion proves it, and the S"A who wrote just plain 'Pat Shacharit.' And that's what everyone does."] – Bracketed text from Kaf haChayim which is clear to me and not part of this question.

ט"ז

פת שחרית. מו"ח ז"ל העתיק ממרדכי ארוך וז"ל וששאלת לפרש שיעור פת שחרית ובאיזה שעה אוכלין אותה דע שאנו לא נהגו בה כל עיקר ואין רבותינו רגילין בה מפני ששמענו **שפת שחרית אינה באה אלא מתבואה רחוקה מישוב ולא שמעה קול תרנגול ולא קול מושכי אניות** והרגילים בה צריכים לאוכלה תדיר כל יום ע"כ נמנעים החכמים ממנה דא"א לעמוד עמה עכ"ל ומי שלא נותן לב לדבר זה ומקיים הדברים כפשוטן לא הפסיד כלום.

Comment: I’d imagine it means wheat not produce

Comment: @Chatzkel The entire city was every morning reliant on flour or grain coming from the countryside? and not to mention rising time, wasn't bread risen overnight or very early morning?

Comment: I think it means that the wheat for the flour must come from afar, a place that does not have roosters or near a place of ships

Comment: It appears that the Mordekhai Arokh may have translated the term פותא (Shabboth 66b) as פת שחרית. See Mital ha-Shamayim, p. 173 by R. Mordekhai Toledano.